# Maps defined on the set of Turing degrees

Tags: lo.logic, gn.general-topology

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the collection  of [Turing degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree). Are there nontrivial maps $\phi:\mathcal{D}\to \mathcal{D}$ which is natural to consider? For instance, I wonder whether maps which are continuous with respect to the [Scott topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_continuity) or the [poset topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poset_topology) on $\mathcal{D}$ have been studied.

Comment: Look up "Martin's conjecture" - very vaguely, it's believed that any reasonably-definable map on the Turing degrees is something like an iterate of the Turing jump.